# Can the following integral be be simplified? $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x_1 - x_0|^{2\beta}}e^{-|x_2 - x_1|^{2\beta}}dx_1 $ for $0 < \beta \leq 1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$x_0, x_1, x_2 \in\mathbb{R}$
I have tried so many things but I can't seem to be able to work it out. I however managed to calculate the following integral ($B>0$):
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
    \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-B|x|^{2\beta}} dx &= 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-Bx^{2\beta}} dx \\
    &= 2B^{-\frac{1}{2\beta}} \int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^{2\beta}}\\
    &= \frac{B^{-\frac{1}{2\beta}}}{\beta} \int_{0}^{+\infty} dx x^{\frac{1}{2\beta} - 1}e^{-x}\\
    &= \frac{B^{-\frac{1}{2\beta}}}{\beta} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2\beta})
\end{split}
\end{align}

I also tried plugging this into wolfram alpha or symbolab but they don't give any answers (but they also didn't for the above integral which I managed to solve in terms of a gamma function).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are we assuming $x_0,x_2$ are both real numbers as well? Or could they be complex?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to provide it (sorry for the late responds but I couldn't comment yet)